# Fatal Error visual studio 2017 - Azure Functions

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017

I'm having a fatal error when I want to debug an Azure Function. here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Azure Function project.
   [image]
2. Select Azure Functions v2 (.NET Core) in the dropdown, then select Http trigger.
   [image]
3. Compile the generated template code and click on the debug button (F5) to get the error.
   [image]

I'm having that issue with Visual Studio Community and Professional. I uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times by trying to clean as much as possible the cached Visual Studio files as suggested in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2017). I also tried to add/remove as many components in Visual Studio Installer without success. Azure Development is checked in Visual Studio Installer.

[image]

It seems that the compute emulator is having some compatibly issues with Visual Studio. Also, the generated project looks like this:

[image]

When I use the older version (v1) that is not using .NET Core, I have no issue to debug using the Azure Compute Emulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... it seems that when we install/upgrade Visual Studio 2017, it does not install the latest version of the cloud extensions in Visual Studio 2017.

You need to go in **Tools** => **Extensions and Updates...**

And then update all the cloud extensions.

[image]

Comment: which version of VS 2017 you are using ?